# Disable Deploy API for specific Stages

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I'm building an API using AWS API Gateway, I will have two or more stages like *dev*, *production* etc.

What i want to do is allow only a group of users to deploy to *production* stage.

What i have accomplished is deny deploy to all stages, but i can't figure out how to specify stages.

Here is my policy to deny Deploy to every stage, also if there is a better way to control I will be glad to hear it.

```
{
    "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": "apigateway:POST",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/{APIID}/deployments"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this, to block the hole stage

```
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/{APIID}/stages",
    "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/{APIID}/stages/production"
]
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-iam-policy-examples.html#api-gateway-policy-example-apigateway-stage-full-access

Comment: Already tried that. This will deny any modification on stage configuration (stage variabels, settings...), but will not deny deployment to the "production" stage.

Also, i'm allowing everything on API Gateway and then o denying some actions, is this correct?